# Save macos bash_profile globally

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, environment-variables

When I setted up an environment variables in my .bash_profile, I need to do "source" command every time, when I reboot my terminal. Where I can set these settings globally for terminal and GUI apps?

I use iTerm2 Build 3.2.9, Macos Catalina Beta,

my bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/pavelrybakov/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/Users/pavelrybakov/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include"
```

ER: When I start a session via iTerm, echo java_home(for example), shows a correct path.

AR: When I start a session via iTerm, echo java_home(for example), shows a blank line of code.

Comment: Please clarify - "When starting a session via iTerm" - you get what?

Comment: `echo java_home` would output the literal string `java_home`, not a blank line. What *exactly* are you running? (And case matters.) Also, the default for iTerm2 is to start a login shell for a new session, which should source `.bash_profile` (if `bash` is default shell), *unless* you also have a `.profile`, which is sourced instead. In short, there are a *lot* of things that could affect what you are observing.

Comment: That said, Catalina has changed the default shell for new users to `zsh`, not `bash`. Are you still actually running `bash`?

Comment: @chepner yes, it's zsh. How can I switch to bash?

Comment: You have several options. The `chsh` command lets you change your default shell. iTerm2 can be configured to use any shell you want, regardless of your default shell (which isn't as important as in Linux, where a default shell is started as soon as you login). Or you can just keep to `zsh` as your interactive shell; it does not affect your ability to run scripts written in `bash`. If you do that, you'll want to read up on `zsh` and learn which configuration files to use. (Very briefly, `.zprofile` replaces `.bash_profile`, and `.zshrc` replaces `.bashrc`.)

Comment: @chepner TY! Your advise is helps me! But my IntelliJ IDEA still doesn't work properly... Maybe you have answer for this question too? `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 7.74 seconds`

Comment: @chepner `.bash_profile` is sourced first, not `.profile`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oops, right. I got that part backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give your OS flavor.

Some flavors don't look specifically in `.bash_profile`, and instead, they look in `.bashrc`.

This could be the case on your system.

Check and see if you have a `$HOME/.bashrc` file.  If you do, you may want to add something like this to the top of your `.bashrc` (under the `#!/bin/bash`, or wherever it's pointing) file and see if it works:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.bash_profile ]
then
    . $HOME/.bash_profile
fi
```

The `.bash_profile` is not getting executed because it is not getting called by the terminal.  This could be OS or shell dependent, and you didn't really give us enough info to go off of.